# How to pass the latitude and longitude values to the ns url?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i use the google api for getting the location information.For that i use the `CLLocationManager` for getting the location latitude and longitude values.And my pblm is how to pass these latitude and longitude values to nsurl .ANd iam directly given the one location values to the url like below.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search           /json?location=40.7143528,-74.0059731&radius=10000&types=school&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM"];
```

I write this one in below method for get and pass the latitude and longitude values.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
}
```

So please tell me how to pass the `newlocation.Coordinates.latitude` and `newlocation.Coordinates.longitude` to that url in that method. Or Is there any way to pass that values in any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this..

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=10000&types=school&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM",newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```

Comment: But it will be given the error like ececution bad access error when that first line executed

Comment: copy and try now. I changed it. use %f for float.. instead of %@.. just try the above line now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, however is brain compiled :)

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
//Filter the location first here, it could be an invalid location or maybe too recent to the last one because this method is called several times in short times of periods.

//Then use the value
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f, %f&radius=10000&types=school&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM", newLocation.lattitude, newLocation.longitude];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromString:address];
//do your thing here...

}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: But it will be given the error like ececution bad access error when that first line executed

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the latitude and longitude when the location manager finds new location to Google API:

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%f,%f&output=csv", newLocation.lattitude, newLocation.longitude];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromString:address];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
NSURL *addressUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@,%@&radius=10000&types=school&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM",newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude, nil]];
```

Comment: I got the error like "request for member 'latitude' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Replace newLocation.latitude by your Lattitude Value and newLocation.longitude with Longitude value ..

Comment: Try newLocation.coordinate.latitude for updated Latitude and same for longitude